# Why is my date being set with only 2 digits for the year in c#?

Tags: c#

In the following code snippet, I set TDate = new DateTime(2013,12,31), but when I look into the object data, TDate is set to 12/31/13 (i am not showing time) instead of 12/31/2013. When I send this to SqlServer, SqlServer naturally complains about the limit on datetime2.  Why is the year not setting to 2013? Please help - what can I do to have 12/31/2013?

```
trxs.Add(new Transaction 
{
  AccountPK = string.Format("{0}{1}", t.acctno, Prefs.BCode),
  Balance = 0.0m,
  BCode = Prefs.BCode,
  ChqNo = t.chq_no.ToString(),
  Details = t.details,
  RowID = (int)t.roid,
  TDate = new DateTime(2013, 12, 31),
  TrxAmount = t.fx_amt,
  TrxDate = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", t.tdate),
  TrxRef = (int)t.tref,
  TrxType = t.trx_type
 });
```

The referenced class is:

```
    public class Transaction
{
    public string AccountPK { get; set; }
    public int RowID { get; set; }
    public DateTime TDate { get; set; }
    public int TrxRef { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public decimal TrxAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    public string ChqNo { get; set; }
    public string TrxDate { get; set; }
    public string BCode { get; set; }
    public string TrxType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How are you looking at `TDate`? Are you sure whatever is displaying `TDate` isn't simply displaying it as a short format?

Comment: Code shown can't produce the date you are claiming in the text (you may *see* it in debugger as "short date" format for some reason, but it does not change the value of `.Year`). You need to provide [MCVE] that demonstrate problem - in current state post sounds like just some debugging misunderstanding.

Comment: TDate is a DateTime.  There is a reason for TrxDate being stored as a string at the moment.  I have a problem with TDate and not with TrxDate.  Once, I can solve TDate - I will not need TrxDate.  Thank you.  If I don't have a solution for TDate, then I will keep TrxDate

Comment: You are probably right but In debug, all other DateTime vars - show correctly - and SqlServer complains - on the date when I try the insert.

Comment: using visual studio - debug to look at the data.  The data is posted to a webserver using HttpClient.  When it arrives there - it is to be inserted into SqlServer.  There it fails - complaining about datetime2 limit. This was working before, a year ago when i first created it - i never noticed anything about dates then

Comment: Alexei - thanks for your help.  I am learning how to use StackOverflow.  I will get better one day - i am sure.  right now - I am just frustrated with this problem.  It should be easy - i have the data, i put it into an array - send it to a webapi - it arrives and should be stored into sqlserver - not rocket science - but it is not working!

Answer (score 0):

Specify the culture in the web.config. E.g.

```
<system.web>
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB"/>
</system.web>
```

Or in code

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
```

**CAUTION**

Your SQL Server must have same culture as your .NET code. You can set the culture in the SQL Server from this MSDN link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190682.aspx

If these two cultures match you will not have this problem anymore.